# Attachments.Add cannot find file

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

This code should fill form fields pulled from an Excel workbook on a PDF document, save it and then email the saved file to a specified address.

I sent multiple emails with the correct attachment.

Today the attachment fails with

> Runtime error: "Cannot find this file, verify the file name and path are correct."

```vb
LastName = .Range("E" & CustRow).Value
FirstName = .Range("D" & CustRow).Value
PayoutDate = .Range("H" & CustRow).Value
TotalPayout = .Range("G" & CustRow).Value
ClientName = .Range("C" & CustRow).Value
Email = .Range("I" & CustRow).Value
ID = .Range("A" & CustRow).Value
CustNum = .Range("B" & CustRow).Value
AmountName = .Range("J" & CustRow).Value
Today = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd")

Body = "<p>&nbsp;</p>" & _
"<p>We greatly appreciate your support as an ambassador of Briggs &amp; Riley. We&#39;re pleased to inform you that your monthly earnings from Briggs &amp; Riley&#39;s Spife program have been successfully processed, and a direct deposit payment will soon be made to your account. Your continued outstanding performance in driving Briggs &amp; Riley sales is truly valued. Here&#39;s to another fantastic month!</p>" & _
"<p>&nbsp;</p>" & _
"<p>Your dedicated Briggs &amp; Riley Team</p>"

NewPDFName = CustNum & LastName & Today & ".pdf"
SavePDFFolder = Worksheets("Create and Send").Range("F10").Value

Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
Application.SendKeys PayoutDate, True
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
Application.SendKeys TotalPayout, True
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
Application.SendKeys FirstName & " " & LastName, True
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
Application.SendKeys AmountName, True

Application.SendKeys "^+(s)", True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00002
Application.SendKeys NewPDFName, True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00003
Application.SendKeys "%(s)", True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00003

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
    .To = Email
    .Subject = "Spife Payout"
    .HTMLBody = "Hello" & " " & FirstName & " " & LastName & Body
    .Attachments.Add NewPDFName
    .DeferredDeliveryTime = DateAdd("n", 10, Now)
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "spifesupport@usluggage.com"
    .Send
```

Comment: You checked that `NewPDFName` and `SavePDFFolder` contain valid path and filenames?

Comment: Specify the full path name for the attachement `Attachments.Add SavePDFFolder & "\" & NewPDFName`

Comment: Thanks guys, I added the "\" between the 2 and made sure that they both contained the specified paths I needed and now it worked. So strange that it worked before with no issue exactly how it's written and today it broke.

Comment: Your workflow has changed - you used to run your code with the current directory set to the attachment location, and it failed when the directory was pointed elsewhere (for  example because you reset it when you opened a file from another location)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look like `NewPDFName` contains a fully qualified file name (both the path and name). Make sure it does. e.g.,

```
NewPDFName = "c:\temp\" CustNum & LastName & Today & ".pdf"
```